# Terminal: Check the status/progress of a running application?

Tags: command-line, ssh, 15.10

Let's say I run a process on machine 1: `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb` and I'd like to check the status of that running process on machine 2. Of course I'd SSH into that box, but what kind of Terminal trickery would I use to see the status/progress of that running process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux` they let you detach from a terminal session then reattach when ever you like. They are fairly easy to use but I would suggest for your first steps to use an application call `byobu` so on the machine where you are going to run your commands on you would do the following

```
sudo apt-get install byobu -y
byobu-enable
byobu
sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sdb
```

At this point you will be able to close your terminal and it will still be running .  Then just ssh back to your machine and it will automatically put you back in the session.

Once you get comfortable with that then look at using `tmux` really powerful tool for doing this.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back.